# Updating cluster layers dynamically in Mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use Mapbox GL JS to draw some points on the map. I also use a cluster to organize the points. My source code is almost the same as [official example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/) in their documentation. The only difference is I have a model in the bottom-left that hides/shows the points, for example when I disable the excellent button on the model the green points will remove on the map as in the images below.

For `unclustered-point` Layer each time the user clicks on the model I update the layer based on the code below, which is works perfectly.

```
map.setFilter('unclustered-point', [
   "all",
   ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
   ["in", ['get', 'color'], ["literal", arrayOfRemainingColor]]
]);
```

My question is, What can I do for updating the clustering layer because each cluster contains some green points, The color of clusters, and a number should update as it happens in the [official example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try with `map.triggerRepaint();`.